# Getting "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." when creating a release in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, powerbi, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am getting the following error when I click on "Create Release"

```
2020-03-16T20:19:34.4515940Z Logging in with a Service Principal
2020-03-16T20:19:34.9209641Z Publishing PowerBI FIle: D:\a\r1\a\_PowerBI\drop\PowerBI, in workspace: contoso with user: 
2020-03-16T20:19:35.0059635Z Getting Power BI Workspace properties; contoso
2020-03-16T20:19:35.6190535Z ##[error]The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
2020-03-16T20:19:35.6575457Z ##[section]Finishing: Power BI Action: Publish
```

I have tried both "User" and "Service Principal" and this error is when I choose "Service Principal"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the error log, looks like you are using this 3rd-party extension -- [Power BI Actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-power-bi-actions)

> To configure a Service Principal with PowerBI you will have to go
>   through this guide:Service principal with Power BI
>
> - ClientId: The client id of the Azure Active Directory application.    **This application should have the appropriate rights in order to use    the Power BI Api.**
> - ClientSecret: The client secret of the application
> - Tenant ID: The identifier of the Azure Active Directory tenant

Service principal just work as an impersonation for user in Azure AD. 
If Service Principal do not have corresponding permission, you need to check it when created.

Here your go: [Use portal to create an Azure Active Directory application and service principal that can access resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal).

> When you have an application that needs to access or modify resources, you must set up an Azure Active Directory (AD) application and assign the required permissions to it. This approach is preferable to running the app under your own credentials because:
>
> - You can assign permissions to the app identity that are different than your own permissions. Typically, these permissions are restricted to exactly what the app needs to do.
> - You do not have to change the app's credentials if your responsibilities change.
> - You can use a certificate to automate authentication when executing an unattended script.

Comment: I am getting this error "An error occurred, Please try again later" when I try to follow the instructions in the link you provided, at "Add role assignment" and the drop down menu "Role" is empty

Comment: @alideeb2022 Did you mean you failed to create a  service principal in Azure? If so, this issue should related to Azure side. Not Azure DevOps Service.

Comment: I have added a trial azure subscription and was ale to follow the instructions in the link you provided and still getting same error.

Comment: Hi @alideeb2022 not sure if the trial azure subscription get enough permission to handle this. Have you checked the Azure subscription permissions?
 Select **My permissions**. Then, select Click here to view complete access details for this subscription. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal  . What's the result if you give the role **Owner**?

Comment: I was able to copy PowerBI report from tenant to tenant by changing the permission in the Tenant setting in PowerBI admin center and alos by granting full permission in App Registration in Azure AD, what I don't understand is why I needed to give full permission for that to work or what is the minimum and sufficient permission (Application / Delegated) that I can give.